# ASP.NET and C# FileUpload

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a asp file upload for pictures and what I want to do is, when the file chosen has the same name as the previous file it should pop something up that says "This image name already exists, do you want to replace it? if yes then it would just override the current picture with the new one but if not then just leave it alone. How can I do this?. Right now I have this. Also if the solution is in javascript I could also use that (but i am not too good with javascript :) ) Thank you

```
<div class="style">
Choose an Image:&nbsp;<asp:FileUpload ID="getImage" runat="server" Width="150px" BorderStyle="Inset" EnableViewState="true" />
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator"
runat="server" ControlToValidate="getImage" CssClass="Error" Display="dynamic" ValidationExpression=".*(\.[Jj][Pp][Gg]|\.[Gg][Ii][Ff]|\.[Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg]|\.[Pp][Nn][Gg])" ErrorMessage="Select a correct file format"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</div>
```

Please be aware I am a total newbie with Javascript so if that is what's going to work please explain as if I was a 5 year old.

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I can figure out if the file exists, but I need to know how I can code it so that if the file chosen matches the name of the old file to prompt that...I got the logic to check for the file names is just that I do not know if the FileUpload has an event I can use and also how to generate the pop up

Comment: I am thinking if there is a way so that I can code in a c# event if(uploadedFile.Name == existingFile.Name) then make a javascript call from c#? can this be done?

Comment: I posted an answer but I don't think it's quite at the 5 year old level... sorry.

Comment: You can't call JavaScript from C# - your .NET code runs on the server, while the JavaScript runs on the client. However, you *can* generate a document.onLoad javascript event handler from C# which, when the page is loaded into the browser, can do whatever you want.

Comment: Patrick, Clear enought lol thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution will perform the check just before postback.  I also use jquery a little bit.

The important piece of the puzzle here is retrieving the previous file name.  I created a PageMethod to do this part.  So in my aspx.cs file I have a function that looks like this:

```
using System.Web.Services;

.......

[WebMethod()]
public static string GetPreviousFileName()
{
    //put logic here to get the filename to compare against.
    return "somefilename.ext";
}
```

You'll need to implement your own logic for how to retrieve the file name.  Another, simpler but less flexible, approach for handling the previous file name would be to add an asp:hiddenfield to your page and populate it with the name of the previous file on page load.  Then you could compare by reading `$('#<%= hiddenField.ClientID %>').val()`.

Next I used the following code for my file upload control and a submit buton:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
<div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fu" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClientClick="return checkDuplicateFile();" Text="Upload File" />
</div>
```

Two important things to note here: The ScriptManager has `EnablePageMethods="true"` and the asp:button has an OnClientClick attribute specified.  Lastly, the javascript part of the solution which retrieves the value from the page method and and compares the file names:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oFilename = "";

    $(function () {
        //get original file name on page load
        PageMethods.GetPreviousFileName(function (result) {
            oFilename = result;
        });
    });

    function checkDuplicateFile() {
        var newVal = $('#<%=fu.ClientID %>').val();
        var newValFile = newVal.substr(newVal.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

        //returning true causes postback, returning false stops postback.
        if (newValFile == oFilename) { return confirm("This image name already exists, do you want to replace it?"); }
        else return true;
    }
</script>
```

Couple of things going on here.  We use our pagemethod to pull in our old filename from the page method on page load (`PageMethods.GetPreviousFileName`).  Next we setup the function which will be called by our buttons onClick event (client side).  The `<%=fu.ClientID %>` snippet of code will output the client side id of the file upload control for use in our javascript.  I do a substring on the file path and extract the file name by pulling back only the text after the last '\' and do the compare.

As my comment in the function says, returning true/false from a function called in the OnClientclick event determines whether a post back occurs.  So if the user clicks yes in the confirmation box then a postback occurs, else if they click no then none occurs.

Hope that at least gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: Wow excellent, just one question. The file uploader comes with a button that reads "Browse"...how do I manipulate it to hide it if it isnot needed?

Comment: I don't believe you can, but even if you can how are users going to upload a file if they can't click the browse button?  Alot of browsers don't allow copy/pasting into the file upload box.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below to your submit button

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?')"
```

**Edit** as someone pointed out this will ask this question without taking in concern previous file and new one. It will do basic job.

My question is whether you doing this for edit mode or in new item mode. I mean are you editing item or adding new one on page you are interested to check?

Comment: The problem is that the submit button does not take place until much later, after other things are filled out. I would like to do it right on the spot. Does the FileUpload have an OnChosen event or something lol

Comment: It has events but these are server side events when you asking for client side one. Writing server/client validation with skills you claim you are now, is out of the scope. Trust me, make it in easy steps.

Comment: what submit button? This doesn't run any checks

Comment: Well I am not an expert, I am kinda new so anything that works is welcome

Comment: @SuperUser555 The example given here is going to ask the question every time a file is uploaded. It doesn't pay attention to whether or not a file with the same name has already been uploaded.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I am thinking if there is a way so that I can code in a c# event if(uploadedFile.Name == existingFile.Name) then make a javascript call from c#? can this be done?

Comment: You could try the CustomValidator, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k.aspx . Near the bottom they talk about custom javascript validation. That function could make an ajax request(e.g. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to check if the file exists. If the file does exists it could ask, as suggested above "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?')"

Comment: Can someone take off the negative vote from Eugene, for some reason I can not. I think he pointed me in the right direction :)